# How to configure downloaded libraries for a Java program written in the command line?

Tags: java

I am playing around with Java in the command line and I was wondering how can I "implement" downloaded Java libraries?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Comment: Start with a "Hello World" program (you will find tons of tutorials online) and then build more functionality from there on.